# Jenkins 2 Pipeline workspaces xxx@script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to Jenkins 2 and pipeline feature, and I am setting up a project to use the Jenkinsfile for pipeline.

I can see there are 3 workspace created:

- project-xxxxx
- project-xxxxx@script
- project-xxxxx@tmp

When I run `tox` in pipeline, it complains about no `tox.ini` found, I suspect it's in side folder `project-xxxxx` which is empty, but the project files are inside `project-xxxxx@script`

Should I use `checkout scm` to populate the workspace with project files? Or am I suppose to use the project files in `project-xxxxx@script` and how do I do it properly?

Can someone please explain to me how those 3 folders work together?

Comment: Indeed, I stumbled upon this, too. Still no documentation about these paths almost one year later, at least nothing I could find.

Answer (score -2):

You should not have to worry about the workspace in a pipeline. You start the build, you get a workspace and anything you checkout out or copy into it should be there.

1. How do you start the pipeline? Inline script, from scm or via a Multi-Branch or similar job type?
2. How are you getting files into your workspace?